# Qt - Focus on a application that has lost focus?

Tags: qt, focus

I would like to know if it's possible to focus on my application even if it has lost focus?

My application is running a thread, and once I exit it, I would like to bring my window application to the front.
I've tried the following code, it works to focus on the widget I'd like to, but if you're on firefox, it will just flash once in taskbar, and don't focus :(

```
this->activateWindow();
this->show();
this->setFocus();
```

EDIT: This would do it, but I don't want my application stay on top... and if I remove the flag, it loses focus =/

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
this->activateWindow();
this->show();
this->setFocus();
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Unless this software is for your own computer only, please don't do this. Any reputable OS will not allow your app to jump to the foreground and disrupt anything else the user may have been doing. Any hack you find that allows you to do this will be just that, a hack, and will result in your software being immediately removed from my computer at least :)

Comment: But that's the purpose of the software. People want that feature, lol.

Comment: Your original solution actually works for me on Ubuntu 10.04, but not on Windows. A hacky solution might be to implement focusOutEvent and remove the StaysOnTop flag there, but I sympathize with Arnold above (Raymond Chen has commented multiple times on similar subjects, with the argument "What if everyone does this?": http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowActive);
```

it worked for me. (Qt 4.8, Windows 7, MinGW 4.4)

EDIT: I've since found that this usually only works if the window is currently minimized. so if it is not working try adding

```
this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMinimized);
```

before it.

Comment: I don't see how this can work on Windows, as the application in the foreground has to explicitly allow your application to come to foreground. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I messed around a little more and updated post regarding my findings (i.e. the workaround I found)

Comment: For me - This made the window blink (in out) but then it still ended up behind