# Stealing focus (for a good reason)

Tags: c++, qt4, focus, qt-creator

I'm working on a clone of [Yakuake](http://yakuake.kde.org) and, if you have used it, you'd know that one of it's features is stealing the focus for easiness.

Basically, you hit the "show" hotkey, the app appears and you can write on it.
You could be doing whatever thing with whatever app, (being Yakuake hidden), but as soon as you hit the hotkey, Yakuake appears and steals the focus. I want to do the same with my app.

I know there are some window manager rules that prevent applications from doing this, but Yakuake is doing it, why I'm not able to do it?

Also, this application is meant to be compatible with Windows, Linux and Mac, so no KDE or Gnome or < insert_your_favourite_window_manager_here > hacks; I won't go the detect-WM-and-do-hack way.

PS: I'm doing that app in C++ and Qt4.

EDIT:

Just to make it clear, I'm not asking for any code (but if you actually have some example, I appreaciate it). I'm asking for a way for doing it. What should I do to make the WM assign the focus to my app. Is there any standard way for doing so?

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230557/qt-focus-on-a-application-that-has-lost-focus can help you.

Comment: @EarlGray I already saw that, and I think it didn't work. Anyways, I'll give it another try. PS: I don't understand the close vote. Is my question wrong/bad in any way? It's not that I'm asking how to make a virus or something...

Comment: I did not vote for close :) But SO appreciates your efforts to do the subject in question before asking, maybe it's the reason (I don't understand it either).

Comment: @EarlGray Yes, I know it wasn't you :)   I was just wondering.

Comment: seems a thought task. Why not 'steal' the Yakuake way?

Comment: @chac Because it's X11 dependant (or maybe even KDE dependant)

Comment: alas, I've not still touched KDE, so Yakuake was unknown to me. But the description is really intriguing. Maybe I'll take the KDE path soon. I'm working integrating Qt and SWI-Prolog...

Comment: @chac this is offtopic, but you should really try Yakuake (if you're not on KDE that's fine, you can still install it). It's amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simpler than I thought. I did an animation with a duration of 0s and at the end of the animation I just did a focus. This did the work.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15464-WindowStaysOnTopHint)....

Comment: I'm not asking for an AlwaysOnTop window (but even if I did, AlwaysOnTop doesn't mean that it'll be able to catch the focus in any way). I'm asking for a way to actually stealing the focus after showing the app (which can be toggled shown/hidden with a hotkey)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a  "show" hotkey or shortcut you'll have to create and use a hook on the keybord.

Qt don't provide such things so you'll have to do it by yourself.

you can have a look at this post : [QT background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425965/qt-background-process-for-keyboard-input-sniffing/7427517#7427517)

I don't know for other OS.

When you'll get the right keyboard event from your hook, you can create a window with the "allwas on top hint" and that should by ok.

Comment: Thank you for the global shortcut TIP but I already have a working code for all platforms. What I'm missing is the focus thing. And as I already said in the comment in the other reply AlwaysOnTop is not the same as FocusOwner. You see, you can have an AlwaysOnTop window (let's say VLC playing a video) and you can have the focus in a Skype chatwindow (writing). See what's the difference?

Comment: Yes I see the difference. I misunderstood your question. Perhaps is there some OS API doing it but i don't know much about that. sorry.